# IE 9 console object uninitialized until developer console is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Assuming I have following HTML

```
<div id="box" style="display:none;">Hello World</div>
<button id="showbutton">Show The Box</button>
```

And following JQuery button handler to show the div

```
$('#showbutton').click(function() {
    console.log('test');
    $('#box').show();
});
```

Notice the `console.log` statement. If I click the button on a freshly opened IE9 browser, it won't work. It seems the console object is not yet initialized. But if I press F12 to open the developer console, the handler will work.

This behavior doesn't exist on Chrome/Firefox.

Is this an expected behavior of console object on IE? Is there a documentation related to javascript console object support on IE?

JSFiddle for the demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/6tHB5/.

To reproduce the problem on IE, you have to close your browser first, run the browser again, then click the button straight away without opening developer console (F12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is unfortunately just how IE works. There are a few possible solutions:

You can  check beforehand if you want to avoid JS errors.

```
$('#showbutton').click(function() {
  if (console) console.log('test');
  $('#box').show();
});
```

Make your own `log` function to check automatically.

```
function log(){
  if (console) console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

You could also mock out the console like this at the top of your page to make life easier:

```
if (!window.console) window.console = {log: function(){}};
```

Answer (score 0):

In IE 9 console object is not defined before it opened, so you should check it before log:

```
$('#showbutton').click(function() {
  if (typeof console != 'undefined') console.log('test');
  $('#box').show();
});
```